# How to add a dynamic validation rule to a form field in dev express

Tags: asp.net-core, devextreme, devexpress-mvc

Good day, I am new to Dev express and also to razor pages.

I have a dev extreme data grid with a list of users, a user has a user type the user type has a min range and a max range for the user id.

What I want is to set a range validation rule on a column on the standard edit form of the datagrid so when you add a new user id the user id should be between for example 1 and 49999. The range is stored in a database. So the user first selects the user type, the usertype table will have a range in it for example a user type of "Employee" will have a range of min 1 max 49999, this range I want to use as validation on my form.

My DevExtreme datagrid code currently :

```
@(Html.DevExtreme().DataGrid<ACS.LIB.BE.User>().ID("userGrid")
.ElementAttr(new { @class = "dx-card wide-card" })
.DataSource(d => d.Mvc().Controller("User")
    .LoadAction("Get").Key("ID")
    .InsertAction("InsertUser")
    .UpdateAction("UpdateUser")
    .DeleteAction("DeleteUser"))
.ShowBorders(false)
.FilterRow(f => f.Visible(true))
.FocusedRowEnabled(true)
.FocusedRowIndex(0)
.ColumnAutoWidth(true)
.ColumnHidingEnabled(true)
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.AddFor(m => m.ID).ValidationRules(val => val.AddRange().Min(100));
    columns.AddFor(m => m.Name);

    columns.AddFor(m => m.UserType.ID).Lookup(lookup => lookup
                    .DataSource(ds => ds.WebApi().Controller("UserType").LoadAction("Get").Key("ID"))
                    .DisplayExpr("Name")
                    .ValueExpr("ID")
                    ).Caption("User Type");
    columns.AddFor(m => m.Department.ID).Lookup(lookup => lookup
                    .DataSource(ds => ds.WebApi().Controller("Department").LoadAction("Get").Key("ID"))
                    .ValueExpr("ID")
                    .DisplayExpr("Name")
                    ).Caption("Department");
    columns.AddFor(m => m.Company.ID).Lookup(lookup => lookup
                    .DataSource(ds => ds.WebApi().Controller("Company").LoadAction("Get").Key("ID"))
                    .ValueExpr("ID")
                    .DisplayExpr("Name")
                    ).Caption("Company");
    columns.AddFor(m => m.Authority);
    columns.AddFor(m => m.Email).ValidationRules(v => v.AddEmail().Message("Please enter a valid email address. yourname@yourdomain.com"));
    columns.AddFor(m => m.Active).FilterValue(true);

})
```

The line I have a problem with is `columns.AddFor(m => m.ID).ValidationRules(val => val.AddRange().Min(100));`

The Min(100) I want to set it dynamically from a data source not hardcoded like it is now, the user first selects the Usertype and then I want to use the UserType table to get the range what the id should be in. So I want to fetch the 100 from my user table but I am not sure what the syntax would be or how I should go about doing it.

My usertype table :
[image]

My insert screen default popup from the edit dialog of the data grid.
[image]

Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to define a [custom validation rule](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxValidator/Validation_Rules/CustomRule/) instead. You can get a **user type** value using the **options.data** parameter in the [validationCallback](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxValidator/Validation_Rules/CustomRule/#validationCallback) function.

Note that the best ASP.NET Core practice is to use model properties' [Data Annotation validation attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/overview?view=aspnetcore-3.0#model-validation)﻿. DevExtreme ASP.NET Core components support them.

You can find code snippets in the [Implement a Custom Validation Rule](https://docs.devexpress.com/AspNetCore/400576/devextreme-based-controls/concepts/data-validation#implement-a-custom-validation-rule) topic.